# Can't connect to ftp server on Windows Server 2022 in LAN in virtual box

Tags: ftp, windows-server-2022

I created a ftp server with read-write access to everybody on Window Server:

[image: configured server]

When I'm trying to connect to `c2` from client's `total commander` I get this (sorry for russian):

[image: error view]

Comment: Hi, could this https://serverfault.com/questions/887176/530-valid-hostname-is-expected-when-setting-up-iis-10-for-multiple-sites answer you ? It's a common error you got if multiple ftp site is binded inside IIS. (aka, the server can have two ftp site, but it direct to the correct one depending on the host the client try to connect to. A missconfig of binding could be your problem too)

Comment: Yea, passing hostname before username helped me. But I created only one server, why it is required?